# Background image resize changes the view in android

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic3 application. Everything is great, except, when uses the keyboard in inputs or the inputs are focused the background image resizes and it makes the view horrible. I googled a lot I found the following questions in forums. Unfortunately, they didn't work for me in ionic3.

[image resize in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682450/ionic2-background-image).
[image resize in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670244/ionic-keyboard-is-resizing-my-background)
And now I'm going to provide some codes.

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      ورود به حساب
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <div class="login">
    <div class="login-form">
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-sm-12>
            <ion-list inset>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label ionitron-bot>
                  <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
                </ion-label>
                <ion-input
                  [(ngModel)]="phone"
                  type="tel"
                  placeholder="794737444"
                ></ion-input>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
        <ion-row>
          <ion-col col-sm-12></ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
**
```

Scss style codes.

```
page-new-user {
    ion-content{
        height: 100%;
    }
  div.login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../../../assets/imgs/bg-01.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    height: 100%;
    div.login-form {
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
  }
}
```

And now I'm going to provide screenshots of the app.

[before focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPMB1.png)
[after focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0IBV.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
 ion-content{
        height: 100%;
        .scroll-content{
            padding-bottom: 0px !important;
        }
    }
  div.login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../../../assets/imgs/bg-01.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 100% 100%;
    height: 100%;
    div.login-form {
      width: 50%;
      height: auto;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
  }
```

should fix this `.scroll-content{padding-bottom: 0px !important;}` added to ion-content stops the ion-scoll component changing its padding.

Comment: on browsing work  but on mobile when open the keyboard the background resize

Comment: sorry I'll have a look and see if i can edit answer

Comment: @RajabMohammadi  `background-size: cover;` is the problem when the phone keyboard pops up the ion content changes size. because the background is set to cover it will resize. `background-size: auto;` would keep the image at its original size. Still looking to see if theres any other way round this